# luatexja-fontspec causes unwanted space in siunitx-exponent

Tags: siunitx, luatexja

Using the `luatexja-fontspec` package for LuaLaTeX leads to unwanted space between the 'minus' and the number in the exponent of numbers/units typed with the `sinunitx` package using the options `mode=text` and `detect-all`. This Problem does not occur when I remove these options or when I remove `luatexja-fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[
    mode=text,
    detect-all,
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{2.5e-10}{mol.L^{-1}}
\end{document}
```

Does someone have a solution to get rid of this unneccessary space? Or do I have to switch to another package for asian characters? (I need a package that recognizes asian characters automatically without typing them inside enviroments or commands. And I definitely need `siunitx` with a proper output.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With luatexja the minus used by siunitx here is a so-called `JAchar` and is replaced with the lua code. You can change this status either globally -- this can affect text outside siunitx too, or inject a `\ltjalchar` so that it is treated as `ALchar` instead.

```
\documentclass[parskip=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[mode=text,detect-all]{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\SI{2.5e-10}{mol.L^{-1}} \\
\char8722 10


%general change
\ltjdefcharrange{1}{"2212}

\SI{2.5e-10}{mol.L^{-1}} \\
\char8722 10

%back to default
\ltjdefcharrange{3}{"2212}

\SI{2.5e-10}{mol.L^{-1}} \\
 \char8722 10


\ExplSyntaxOn
%local solution, put inside \AtBeginDocument in the preamble
 \tl_set:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl {\ltjalchar`\^^^^2212}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\SI{2.5e-10}{mol.L^{-1}} \\
\char8722 10
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also make a feature request for luatexja. They could add the patch for siunitx.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, I get several error messages when I place the `ExplSyntax` part within `\AtBeginDocument{...}` into the preamble (`! Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`, `Missing $ inserted`,  `! Double subscript. \begin{document}`, `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`)

Comment: \ExplsyntaxOn must be before \AtBeginDocument{} and the off command behind.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and it must be placed after `siunitx` is loaded otherwise it has no effect. Now it works.